# How do I extract current url so that it appears beside each extracted output for each webpage?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

How can this best be achieved?  It is extracting team, team odds, team 2, team lay odds but not href beside each of these results which I am desiring to easily access that webpage.

Currently it is crashing after extracting one age however deleting though this does not solve the issue of wanting to extract href and append beside data extracted

```
get_url = driver.current_url

# Printing the URL
print(get_url)
Links = driver.current_url

for value4 in Links:
    # print(value3.text)
    Links.append(value4.get_attribute('href'))
    print(Links.get_attribute("href"))
#  layOddsList.append(value4.get_attribute('href'))
```

Full below:

```
import os
import shutil
import time
import pandas as pd
import webdriver_manager.chrome
import webdriver_manager.chrome
from openpyxl import Workbook
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
service = Service('driver/chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(webdriver_manager.chrome.ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.get('https://www.betfair.com.au/exchange/plus/en/football-betting-1/14/')
WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".name:nth-child(1) , bf-coupon-table:nth-child(1) tr:nth-child(1) .matched-amount-value"))
scroll = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".coupon-page-navigation__label--next")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", scroll)

try:
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#cookie-holder span").click()
except:
    pass

team1List = []
backOddsList = []
team2List = []
layOddsList = []
###############
linkslist = []
##############
i = 1
while i < 2:
    try:
        time.sleep(2)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".name:nth-child(1)")))
        WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".name:nth-child(1) , bf-coupon-table:nth-child(1) tr:nth-child(1) .matched-amount-value"))
        scroll = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".coupon-page-navigation__label--next")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", scroll)
        NextStory = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'bf-coupon-page-navigation > ul > li:nth-child(4) > a')))
        match = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".name:nth-child(1)")
        matches = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "CSS_SELECTOR")

        Team1 = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".name:nth-child(1)")
        for value in Team1:
            print(value.text)
            team1List.append(value.text)

        BackOdds = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".coupon-runner:nth-child(1) .back-selection-button .bet-button-price")
        for value2 in BackOdds:
            print(value2.text)
            backOddsList.append(value2.text)

        Team2 = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".name:nth-child(2)")
        for value1 in Team2:
            print(value1.text)
            team2List.append(value1.text)

        driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "bf-coupon-page-navigation > ul > li:nth-child(4) > a[class = 'coupon-page-navigation__link coupon-page-navigation__link--next']")

        LayOdds = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".coupon-runner:nth-child(1) .lay-selection-button .bet-button-price")
        for value3 in LayOdds:
            print(value3.text)
            layOddsList.append(value3.text)

        WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "bf-coupon-page-navigation > ul > li:nth-child(4) > a[class = 'coupon-page-navigation__link coupon-page-navigation__link--next']")))
#########################ISSUE HERE WITH CODE ########################################################################################################################
#########################ISSUE HERE WITH CODE ########################################################################################################################
        get_url = driver.current_url

        # Printing the URL
        print(get_url)
        Links = driver.current_url

        for value4 in Links:
            # print(value3.text)
            Links.append(value4.get_attribute('href'))
            print(Links.get_attribute("href"))
        #  layOddsList.append(value4.get_attribute('href'))
#########################ISSUE ABOVE WITH CODE ########################################################################################################################
#########################ISSUE ABOVE WITH CODE #######################################################################################################################

        NextStory.click()

        for match in matches:
            driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "bf-coupon-page-navigation > ul > li:nth-child(4) > a[class = 'coupon-page-navigation__link coupon-page-navigation__link--next']")
            WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "bf-coupon-page-navigation > ul > li:nth-child(4) > a[class = 'coupon-page-navigation__link coupon-page-navigation__link--next']")))
            NextStory.click()
    except:
        i = 6
        print('error')
        pass

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Team1': team1List,
    'Back Odds': backOddsList,
    'Team2': team2List,
    'Lay Odds': layOddsList,
    'links': linkslist
})

df.to_excel('betfair.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', sheet_name='Sheet_name_1', index=False)
```

output:
[image]

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code, properly formatted. Also post the full error message, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring.

Comment: @JeffC Full code not reproducible example?  Output is blank for href though team, team odds and team 2, team 2 odds is showing at least

Comment: Full code is too much. We're not interested in debugging your 150 line script. The intent of SO is to answer focused questions. Currently this is not a focused question. Read the links in my first comment carefully and follow the instructions there to simplify your code then post it here.

Comment: @JeffC I mean that was the short version, the original has around 100 more lines of code but I suppose I can shorten it more to be fair.  Good point

Comment: The problem you are having is that the href isn't printing. Focus on that. Take out all code not related to that issue so that you have a super simplified version that just goes to the page and tries to get the href and fails. That we can work with. This process may feel tedious but it forces you to look at your code more carefully and get rid of anything that doesn't matter. In a lot of cases, you will find the issue yourself. This is a good practice to get into to solve your own problems. If you get there and still haven't solved it, it will simplify what we need to look at.

Comment: @JeffC More readable now you reckon?  The issue is to do with the href extraction around line 74

Comment: No. Still WAY too much code. I can guarantee you that 95+% of that code has nothing to do with the href not printing. Make a copy of your script if you aren't using a code repo and start deleting until you have nothing but navigate to site and print the first href and see if that works.

Comment: Also you are referencing line numbers but we don't know what line you are referring to

Comment: @JeffC Definitely this is the issue:         Links = driver.current_url
        print(Links)
        for value4 in Links:
            Links.append(value4.get_attribute('href'))
            print(Links.get_attribute("href"))

Comment: If you decide to clean up your code, let me know. Until then there's nothing more I can do. I don't have access to the website, you haven't provided relevant HTML, and there's WAY too much code to process for an answer.

Comment: I removed everything I could.  If I remove anything else the code won't be able to reproducible as it won't run at all.  The site requires an Australian vpn.  I also marked where the issue with code is #########################ISSUE ABOVE WITH CODE as well as wrote it seperately in code format#################################################################

Comment: From your code, found some issues: first one - you are storing the current page's url in 'Links' then inside the for loop, you are appending the urls to 'Links'.  you didn't declare 'Links' as a list. First declare Links as a list, then store multiple elements using 'driver.find_elements()' then you can iterate through Links.  Also, what is the actual issue you got?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't able to check the website, because it is blocked. But, from your code I am assuming that you cannot get the list of urls, for that try the below code:

```
Links = driver.find_elements("<element's property using xpath or cssselector or ...>")

url_list = []
for i in range(len(Links)):
    url_list.append(Links[i].get_attribute("href"))

for url in url_list:
    driver.get(url)
    print(url)
```

Comment: Unfortunately the page does the page does not have href to extract per normal so I have to use Links = driver.current_url but this is not creating desired output

Comment: I think get_attribute("href")) is not correct way for current url

Comment: Yeah so output is none atm so nearly fixed

Comment: Thanks I finally got it to work as was overthinking it.   Code should be:         links = driver.current_url
        for value4 in LayOdds:
            print(driver.current_url)
            linkslist.append(driver.current_url)

Comment: If this works for you, accept this as the answer